# How to implements java timer in server side?

Tags: java, timertask

Hello I am currently working on a middleware application

Im using JSF and primefaces and the deployment is in tomcat server ,
I was able to develop a notification system using JAVA.mail and i am using java timer to schedule the notification every 24H

For the moment it works fine when I run my main class but when i run the whole project the process of javaTimer doesn't work and i have no idea how to make run in server side without launching the class Main

So i ask if should add something to make it run when i launch my project

Here my code :

```java
public class Job1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // execute method review_date() every 1 minute
        risk r = new risk();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    r.review_date2();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000 * 60);
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use Quartz for scheduling?

Comment: @Kaan i found diffuclt im a newbie btw

Comment: Most serverside frameworks have annotations for scheduling jobs. I've never used JSF, but I would start with looking for a Schedule() annotation.

Comment: @akarnokd  thanks a lot man , it function very well !

Comment: You can use a `ScheduledExecutorService` as shown in the [correct Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72707239/642706) by akarnokd. Indeed I have done so myself. But I suggest taking the easier and less risky approach of moving from Tomcat to another Jakarta EE server that supports [*Jakarta Concurrency*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/concurrency/). Examples include Payara, Glassfish, OpenLiberty, WildFly, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I need app-wide resources, I usually implement the `ServletContextListener`, then specify it to be run in `web.xml`. However, swing timers likely don't work so you'll need a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead.

```java
package mypackage;

import javax.servlet.*;

public class MainContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    ScheduledExecutorService service;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        service = newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        risk r = new risk();
        service.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            try {
                r.review_date2();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        service.shutdown();
    }
}
```

```xml
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
 id="WebApp_ID" 
version="4.0">
  <!-- etc. -->
  <listener>
    <listener-class>mypackage.MainContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You can skip the `web.XML` configuration by annotating your class with [`@WebListener`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.1-doc/servletapi/jakarta/servlet/annotation/WebListener.html). Easy-peasy.